# Product page not displayed correctly

Tags: error, magento2.2.6, page

We are new in Magento, version <sup>2.2.6</sup>.

Today we noticed our product listing page have errors, there are some `css` code, also the entire layout is wrong, I have well attached a picture to this.

Please kindly check and return to us how to resolve this problem.

Many thanks!

Nicole[image]

Comment: Can you share you product page content ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the cache. Try running these codes in your Magento 2 root directory one by one:

1. `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `php bin/magento cache:clean`
4. `php bin/magento cache:flush`